# Autocomplete using values from AJAX

Tags: tabulator

I have a table using tabulator.

Everything works great, but I am trying to get autocomplete working with Ajax

What I am trying is:

```js
var customerNumbers = [];

var table = new Tabulator("#edi-table",
    ajaxURL: baseUrl + '/PaginatedEndPoint',
    pagination: "remote",
    paginationSize: 30,
    paginationSizeSelector: [30, 60, 100, 200],
    ajaxSorting: true,
    ajaxFiltering: true,
    selectable: true,
    cellEdited: function (cell) {
        cell.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#32CD32";
    },
    dataLoading: function () {
        customerNumbers = ["11", "12", "13"];
    },
    columns: [
        {
            title: "CustomerNumber", field: "CustomerNumber", headerFilter: "input", editor: "autocomplete", editorParams: {
                searchFunc: function (term, values) {
                    var matches = [];

                    values.forEach(function (item) {
                        if (item.value === term) {
                            matches.push(item);
                        }
                    });
                    console.log(matches);
                    return matches;
                },
                listItemFormatter: function (value, title) {
                    return "Mr " + title;
                },
                values: customerNumbers
            }
        }
    ]
```

However, this does not show any predictions value predictions for me, it seems that autocomplete is built before "dataLoading" or any other Callback (I have tried many) is called.

I have tried to make an auxilary array in the style of values like {Title: "Mr + title", value: "title"} and then assign it in the searchFunc, and it didn't work despite being returned in matches.

Is it even possible to dynamically create autofill?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the current autocomplete functionality does not allow for the editorParams to take a function as an argument to set the dropdown values. You can set it with an object of key/values if you can send that via AJAX, but as far as dynamically setting, altering, or searching the data, it seems like that's impossible to do at the moment.

The other option would be use the editor:"select", which can take a function to set its editorParams. It's not the best solution, but it's the one I had to go with at the moment.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/2112) on the Tabulator docs, but so far no response from the developers.

I wish I had a better answer for you!

Comment: Thank you so much for leaving a reply! I saw that post, and actually managed to do exactly that. I have linked my solution to the post that you have provided.